# Mounting a (semi-?) rebalanced btrfs drive

Tags: btrfs

Have a 2 drive raid1 btrfs array on Ubuntu 16.04 that I no longer need to be raid1.  Thought I would try separating the the disks and converting one to a single drive to keep the data following [these instructions](https://trello.com/c/FdeJ2SrX/8-btrfs-single-disk-raid1-single-disk-conversion):

```
umount t
remove disk t1---
mount /dev/t1 t -o degraded
btrfs bal start -mconvert=single -dconvert=single t
btrfs dev delete missing t
btrfs bal start -mconvert=dup
```

Had to reboot [don't ask] after the `btrfs bal start -mconvert=single -dconvert=single t` step was completed.  Before the reboot I verified that the disk was still mounted at "t" and I could see all the files and directories I expected on it.

Post-reboot, I can't find a way to continue the process.  I can't mount it normally:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/t
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

$ dmesg | tail
[ 2885.993255] BTRFS info (device sdc1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2886.021902] BTRFS: failed to read chunk tree on sdc1
[ 2886.031164] BTRFS: open_ctree failed
```

And I can't mount it degraded (the same way I did before the rebalance):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/t -o degraded
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

$ dmesg | tail
[ 3110.756320] BTRFS info (device sdc1): allowing degraded mounts
[ 3110.756330] BTRFS info (device sdc1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 3110.838626] BTRFS info (device sdc1): bdev /dev/sdc1 errs: wr 470683, rd 503082, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 3111.986155] BTRFS: missing devices(1) exceeds the limit(0), writeable mount is not allowed
[ 3112.019429] BTRFS: open_ctree failed
```

So I can't continue the procedure.  Is there a way to continue?  As I mentioned earlier, the partition seemed to be healthy before the reboot.  Obviously one solution would be to perform the procedure on the other drive in the raid1 pair, but that drive is probably in worse shape (system rebooted before balancing was complete).

This isn't a crisis - my data is backed up. I'm just trying to avoid copying 4TB, and perhaps the solution would help someone else in the future.